# How to pass style as a extraprop in map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a Table and it has different columns.

Currently, I am writing the `Column` component for each column separately but I want to improve my code and use the `map` so that I have to just write the `Column` component one time.

Here's what I have now which is working fine:

```
<Column
  dataKey="id"
  label={Translate.string('ID')}
  width={60}
  cellRenderer={({dataKey, rowIndex}) => _cellRenderer(dataKey, rowIndex)}
/>
<Column
  dataKey="title"
  label={Translate.string('Title')}
  width={600}
  cellRenderer={({dataKey, rowIndex}) => _cellRenderer(dataKey, rowIndex)}
/>
<Column
  id="status"
  dataKey="status"
  label={Translate.string('Status')}
  width={150}
  style={{justifyContent: 'space-evenly'}}
  cellRenderer={({dataKey, rowIndex}) => _cellRenderer(dataKey, rowIndex)}
/>
```

Now I am trying to code using `map` like this:

```
{[
  ['id', Translate.string('ID'), 60],
  ['title', Translate.string('Title'), 600],
  ['status', Translate.string('Status'), 150, {style:{justifyContent: 'space-evenly'}}],
].map(([key, label, width, ...extraProps]) => (
  <Column
       key={key}
       dataKey={key}
       label={label}
       width={width}
       {...extraProps}
       cellRenderer={({dataKey, rowIndex}) => _cellRenderer(dataKey, rowIndex)}
  />
))}
```

I am not able to apply the `style` prop for the `status` data Key.

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not passing the `extraprops` correctly:

`...extraprops` -> `extraprops`

This worked:

```
{[
  ['id', Translate.string('ID'), 60],
  ['title', Translate.string('Title'), 600],
  ['status', Translate.string('Status'), 150, {style:{justifyContent: 'space-evenly'}}],
].map(([key, label, width, extraProps]) => (
  <Column
       key={key}
       dataKey={key}
       label={label}
       width={width}
       {...extraProps}
       cellRenderer={({dataKey, rowIndex}) => _cellRenderer(dataKey, rowIndex)}
  />
))}
```